# Intellij code completion fixed?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

Enable code completion problems within Intellij / Java.

```
List<String> newList = new ArrayList<>();
```

If writing: `newList.` the code completion that popups are only cast, field and so on...

Is it even possible to get the "class" methods like in other editors such as Eclipse, Android Studio and so on...

Comment: can you show use more code?

Comment: Why don't you contact their support?

Comment: I checked here first because this is often better than their direct support. Updated the question.

Comment: You may also always be able to answer like you did "Why dont you contact their support?" for many many questions in here.

Comment: @Mikael your question isn't about programming problem, its about feature you would like to have in a commercial software

Comment: Sure true, but is it possbile to have an answer here maybe anyway ?

Comment: You can ask it to stackoverflow, but it may be worth including the IDE tag to avoid confusion. I've tried to recreate your problem - I see a full list of class methods. What is it you see exactly?

Comment: what you want is not code completion, it's for the IDE to correct your spelling errors for you. But what if they're not and you deliberately use a different spelling, you'd come back and complain about your deliberately missspelled word being corrected...

Comment: Sorry fixed misspelling that was NOT the case here. Seems like the invoke and indexing not working correctly.

Comment: Do you maybe have your own class named `List` somewhere, which is being picked up instead of the standard `java.util.List`?

Comment: -> Jesper, no i also tried with String s = new String();  s.   but nothing here either still maybe missing something else such as indexing somehow?

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Check the following settings screenshot above.

Comment: No not working :( I believe it can be something with the indexing ?